# How to overwrite a library in CSS?

Tags: html, css, angular

We have a library that we are using which is called "md" when using it for css.

It has "display: -webkit-box" that is throwing off the styling which is not aligning navigation bar link horizontally.

In Chrome, I can disable it, and it works fine. But, how can I disable it in css? !important doesn't seem to work.

```
.md-list-item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 2.75rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the angular.json at the styles section. There you may select which styling you are using. If you want to override that .md-list-item you need to have your angular.json this way:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
        "styles.css"
      ]
```

Then you may edit the same class in your styles.css so now the priority is in the styles.css and not in the angular material css